# Installation of owncloud-client in ubuntu

Tags: server

Hey guys, I am new here and here is my question.
I just installed owncloud5 using Ubuntu Linux command line in a terminal and my next job is to install owncloud-client. I actually did that but the problem is that i can't run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data owncloud-client
```

An error display like this:

```
chown: cannot access `owncloud-client': No such file or directory
```

I need a help, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The path `owncloud-client` was not found, as mentioned in the error message.

Try to use the full path like this:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/owncloud/owncloud-client/`

Put the right path into the command, matching your installation.

Comment: i did that but still it said like this               chown: cannot access `/opt/owncloud/owncloud-client/': No such file or directory

Comment: The Path `/opt/owncloud/owncloud-client/` was an example. You have to use the path matching your installation.

Comment: to make it clear, when installing owncloud i did n't 've any problem it installed and stored in **/var/WWW/** directory but now i checked there and only owncloud directory appears.

Comment: i did the following **sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/WWW/owncloud/owncloud-client/**                               **chown: cannot access `/var/WWW/owncloud/owncloud-client/': No such file or directory** still nothing changed .

Comment: The file/directory you want to chown is not there! You have installed the Server in `/var/www/` - OK. Why do you want to install the client on the same machine? Try to install the client as shown here: http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:devel&package=owncloud-client

Comment: The reason is that i have to ! its a necessary/must to install owncloud-client after installing owncloud server bcoz it used to link/sync my owncloud server to my desktop. After i finished installing owncloud-client i have two softwares which used to sync these are, **(ocsync-0.70.6 and mirall-1.2.4)**. so before i installed these two i have two finish owncloud-client installation procedures and **sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/WWW/owncloud/owncloud-client/** but this step holds me down if am not clear u can check on owncloud.org, how the installation steps carried away! thanks alot .